# Clone RDS between two AWS EB environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have Elastic Beanstalk application with two environments: *env1* and *env2* Each environments has its own RDS instance (Postgres), *db1* and *db2* respectively. I need to programmatically clone *db1* to *db2*. That is, after performing the "cloning", the two databases have the same content (the original content in *db2* can be erased).

If the *db1* is changed during the task execution, *db2* doesn't have to respect the changes, that is, it is OK when *db2* contents are equal to *db1* contents just before the task is started, not after finishing.

There are three things I've figured out:

1. Database replication does not resolve my problem. I don't want two databases synced all the time. I just want them to be "synced" after performing the task and then they can diverge.
2. I was able to solve my problem by doing this: a) create snapshot of *db1*, b) change instance identifier of *db2*, c) restore database instance from snapshot from a) with the original identifier from b). This solves the problem, however it takes very long even for very small databases (there is 10-20 min overhead due to environment changing, instance rebooting etc.). (Note: renaming and starting a new instance has to be done, because RDS cannot restore existing instance from snapshot.)
3. Perform dump of *db1* and load it on *db2*... **how to do this?** I have an AWS user that has access to both EB app environments (in *env1* there are credentials for *db1* and in *env2* there are credentials for *db2*). I would prefer if I wouldn't have to send the dumps over the internet.
4. Is there any better way?

I hope I made the problem clear. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You could script #3 using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`. Not sure if that meets your "not over the internet" criteria, though.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that RDS instances are configured to be accessible only from EB instances (and I would very much prefer to keep it that way). So these would have to run on EB instances - how to do that? I can of course do it manually via `eb ssh`, but that cannot be automated. Also, I don't want this to be a part of the app being deployed.

Comment: There's nothing magic about `eb ssh` - it's just a wrapper around regular old `ssh`. In fact, when you run `eb ssh`, it'll show you the `ssh` command it ends up running - something like `INFO: Running ssh -i /Users/petr/.ssh/server.pem ec2-user@111.222.333.444`. With that info, you can certainly automate remote commands, via something like `ssh -t ec2-user@111.222.333.444 "pg_dump -h ebserver-db.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U ebadmin ebdb -f /tmp/ebdb_dump.sql"`.